# Setting QAction with no associated buttons in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, actions, button

I have a function that sets up some QActions and sets some keyboard shortcuts:

```py
def set_num_edit_shortcuts(self):
    self.right_next_action = QAction(parent=iface.mainWindow())
    self.right_next_action.triggered.connect(self.jump_to_next)
    self.right_next_action.setShortcut(Qt.Key_Right)
    self.left_prev_action = QAction(parent=iface.mainWindow())
    self.left_prev_action.triggered.connect(self.jump_to_prev)
    self.left_prev_action.setShortcut(Qt.Key_Left)
    self.up_flip_action = QAction(parent=iface.mainWindow())
    self.up_flip_action.triggered.connect(self.flip_number)
    self.up_flip_action.setShortcut(Qt.Key_Up)
```

The documentation for `QAction` is a bit confusing to me and I'm not sure this is right. I just want the right, left, and up arrow keys to trigger some functions, but all they do now is pan the map to the right, left, and up so clearly my code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So making actions with no buttons didn't work and I tried making buttons for these actions and setting visibility to false and that also did not work so my solution was to keep the buttons visible but make their width 0 so they don't actually show up and now my arrow keys work for these shortcuts.